# Is open quotes missing in the developer story join page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, developer-story

In the Developer Story [joining page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join), I see the below quote without the open quotes:

> [image: Quote - without open quotes]

Usually quotes are surrounded by the open and close quotes, like the below:

> [image: Quote - with open quotes]

After inspect the elements, I see this [SVG](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/timeline.svg?v=aac0afd7f4ca) file used to load the close quotes, but in the same file there is no icons for open quotes exist.

So it is purposely avoided the open quotes in that section?

Comment: I actually like how this currently looks. The open quotes seem so out of place once you put them there it just makes the thing look bulky. If you look carefully you can see that the end quotes are actually inside the text (considered part of the text and align accordingly). The quote remains a quote with or without the opening quotes. Doesn't really make a difference. Still interested in if this is intentional or not.

Comment: @ThomasYates : The quote remains a quote with or without the close quotes too. Why they added close quotes alone is the question. Surely they need some alignment change if they add the open quotes.

Comment: Because it looks good?

Comment: It's amazing how people spot stuff like this, I had to look at your post twice to even notice it here :)

Comment: The open quotes definitely seem out of place, but so do unbalanced quotes, especially on a site like this. I'd rather have no quotes.

Comment: To me, the text with just closing quotes looks weird, `as if it had a closing parenthesis)`. Is it some American cultural thing?

Comment: @anatolyg no, it's not. It's obviously a mistake... and I can't tell if Thomas is trolling. :P

Comment: @canon definitely not trolling. I like it.

Comment: Because they foretold it?

Comment: For the record, I told the designers I thought it looked dumb too, but they went to design school and just stared at me funny. Sorry guys and gals, I tried :(

Comment: @NickCraver did you also tell them that having the closing quote aligned to the bottom of the text is also weird? Looks like commas...

Answer (score 2):

I've raised this with the design team for Developer Story and the missing open quote is a designer-y thing, so this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). I agree that it looks a bit weird, but it's not something that we're going to change...blame designers!

Comment: Your designers are going to destroy the English Language as we know it.  Don't folks get enough help mangling English with their cell phones without our assistance?  For the record, "weird" is not a design esthetic, unless you're channeling Tim Burton.

Comment: It's not limited to our designers, I guess it's a design thing. Maybe Tim Burton influences them all.

Comment: Seems like the dyslexic way to follow [this rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96608/why-does-the-multi-paragraph-quotation-rule-exist)